# How to delete folder drive api

Tags: php, permissions, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

**I am unable to delete a folder** (created by another person) even if I try to change the rights, I have a console application and the current authenticated user can do the following :

1. create folders/files
2. move files

Scopes:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
```

### Tries:

1.Set permissions to the current user

```
public function deleteFolder(\Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $folder)
{
    $permission = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $permission->setRole( 'owner' );
    $permission->setType( 'user' );
    $permission->setEmailAddress('someId@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
    $permission = $this->googleDriveClient->permissions->create( $folder->getId(),$permission,array('transferOwnership'=>true));
    $this->googleDriveClient->files->delete($folder->getId());
}
```

Result:

> [Google_Service_Exception]          {
>   "error": {
>       "errors": [
>        {
>         "domain": "global",
>         "reason": "internalError",
>         "message": "Internal Error"
>        }
>       ],
>       "code": 500,
>       "message": "Internal Error"        }                                  }

2.Set permission **type** to **anyone**

> ```
> public function deleteFolder(\Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $folder)
> {
>     $permission = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
>     $permission->setRole( 'owner' );
>     $permission->setType( 'anyone' );
>     $permission = $this->googleDriveClient->permissions->create( $folder->getId(),$permission,array('transferOwnership'=>true));
>     $this->googleDriveClient->files->delete($folder->getId());
> }
> ```

Result:

> [Google_Service_Exception]
>   {
>   "error": {
>
> ```
> "errors": [                                                                
>  {                                                                         
>   "domain": "global",                                                      
>   "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",                                 
>   "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file  ."                                                         
>
>  }                                                                         
> ],                                                                         
> "code": 403,                                                               
> "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."      }
> ```
>
> }

try 3: Impersonate the creator

```
$this->googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
$this->googleClient->setSubject('x@domain.com');//if removed everything works
```

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
>   Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`
>   resulted in      a `401 Unauthorized` response:
>   {
>   "error": "unauthorized_client",
>   "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request.",
>   "error_uri": ""
>   }

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there something in the folder?  Did you remove the permissions for the other people?   I would stick with your first version it looks close.  Note drive permissions are a pain.

Comment: Folder is empty,I am just trying to add a permission to get rid of it. Pain dearly noted

Comment: Ideas: Do a permissions.list after your create see what it created.   If there is anyone else once you have owner rights delete them.   then list again to make sure it actually did it.   Then delete the folder.    (Like pulling teeth pain)

Comment: hey , did you managed to solve 2? I'm stuck on this in my app (

Comment: @aleXela Sorry I couldn't, you could move them to a temp directory and delete items from time to time. The project I worked on was postponed so I didn't investigate further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the owner of the folder can delete the folder. 
Use a service account [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), take the identity of the owner of the folder [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

Once authorized as the owner of the folder it should be possible to delete the folder.

Comment: I am using a service account and enabled DWD, the folder is shared with the email of the service account ("can edit")...I'm lost

Comment: Are you authorised as the owner of the folder? => the email address should be the owner of the folder, not the service account email address.

Comment: Is the client id in the security panel of g suite, and with the right scopes? Is the Drive api enabled in the project? Is the domain wide authorisation enabled for the service account?

Comment: Yes to all... P.S: I have a python script that does exactly the same things I want to do but now I want to "translate' it to PHP for maintainability (all credentials and settings were copied). It's annoying I can't delete an empty folder but can create files and folders etc...

Comment: The only difference is that for deleting a folder you need to be the owner of the folder. That is the reason why I suggest a service account. I still suspect the domain wide delegation, it is a separate checkbox on the service account in the cloud console project. 100% sure that is checked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127206/discussion-between-jasper-duizendstra-and-ka-lin).